# Assign a task action is missing in dropdown list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm making a custom approval workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013, I am currently unable to find **ASSIGN A TASK** in my action drop down list. I don't know why.

Anyone encountered this error?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on which workflow platform you are using, SharePoint 2010 or SharePoint 2013.

Whenever we create workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013, we can choose between `SP2013 workflow` and `SP2010 workflow`.

The SP2013 workflow has the **Assign a Task** action, while SP2010 workflow doesn't include this.

If you didn't configure 2013 platform for SharePoint 2013 Designer, you need to configure 2013 platform for the SharePoint Designer 2013, then check if it works.

Please refer [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588(v=office.15).aspx) to configure workflow for SP2013.

Found reference [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9af8a1d1-96a4-45ed-a57f-7097a98f12aa/assign-a-task-action-missing-in-spd-2013-list-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomization).